# How to identify ORM - Propel calls in many lines of Symony code?

Tags: orm, symfony1, propel

I am new to Propel. And I have a project using Propel. And I need to identify all Propel calls in many lines of code. The project is made in Symfony.

By what specifications can I find all Propel calls ?

I mean evrey `Propel::getConnection()` is just a connections which can be used in multiple Propel calls ?

Or shall I need to look for every `new Criteria();` and `[TheObiect]Peer::` ?

Comment: Are the actual Propel methods important, or do you just need the queries?  For the latter, you can activate symfony's development environment and use the developer bar.

Comment: Actually, yes! I need to identify also the Propel methods. How can I activate symfony's development environment and how can I use the developer bar to help me in this?

Comment: The dev environment is the one you are working in by default, and the developer toolbar should be in the upper-right hand corner of every page by default as well. However, that doesn't help you to find the actual Propel methods, just the queries. What version of Propel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connections are (in my experience at least) totally handled behind the scenes. They are created automatically if needed and re-used if available. So searching for Propel::getConnection() will not help. You'll need to at least search for what you listed above. Even raw model objects have references to the Peers, like in ModelObject->save(). What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to migrate the project from Propel 1.2 to Doctrine 1.4. The project is not made by me, so first I need to identify all Propel calls before I begin to work.

Comment: Makes sense, I see. I think I would start by searching for all the (Object)Peer as you say, and also any (Object) references.